# I am trying to build android application but have an error in my xml

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

```
<!-- Footer Start -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- Footer Ends -->
```

The error says`no orientation specified and the default is horizontal`. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically.

Comment: is this `LinearLayout` contains any child ? if no then just `clean` and `build` again otherwise put some `orientation` like `android:orientaion="vertical"` or `android:orientaion="horizontal"`

Answer (score 1):

set

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

for `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Add [orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation) to your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Android Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) is a tool which scans Android project sources for potential bugs.

You should add `android:orientation="horizontal"` or `android:orientation="vertical"`

in `LinearLayout` block.i.e. rewrite as

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Footer Start -->
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" ><!-- or horizontal -->

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Footer Ends -->
```